# Can anyone show me some good sites about HTML5?

Tags: html

As the great development of HTML5,I think it is the right time to learn much more about HTML5, so can you tell me some good sites which introduce much knowledge about HTML5. thx a millious,my friends

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take some time to read the **[FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)** on what questions are suitable on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should google for it. Still I would suggest -

http://diveintohtml5.info/

http://html5doctor.com/

Comment: It is serious that w3c has no authority of the corresponding tech?

Answer (score 0):

[www.w3school.com](http://www.w3school.com) is also best site for learning HTML5

Comment: @VenkatReddy - no it isn't. (see http://www.w3fools.com for arguments against w3schools)

Comment: do you really mean to anti-w3school ?